# Whether ask other website's content allowed in SuperUser?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about another site's QnA path.
I want to know the below famous site whether is a forum for QA.

```
https://isocpp.org/
```

---

is this type question allowed to ask in superuser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

It literally says on our [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> and it is not about …
> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,